# Какую админку лучше взять для проетов ларавеля?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

Нужно для своего проекта добавить админку с доступом к ней разными ролями и ограничением доступа к функционалу по ролям. Ищу для начала простенький пакет админки. Пробовал поставить Vojager, но пока не поддается. Документации маловато. Лезут ошибки, которые не получается устранить. Возможно есть попроще админка с хорошей документацией. Какую админку лучше взять для начала?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по звездам две самых кртутых на гитхабе это [the-control-group/voyager](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager)(6.9k) и [z-song/laravel-admin](https://github.com/z-song/laravel-admin)(4.4k). Дальше уже не такие гиганты, это две самые крутые.

Вот сборка всех laravel админок, можете посортировать:  https://github.com/topics/laravel-admin?o=desc&s=stars

Я никогда не использовал админки, если хорошо разбераешься во фронтенде, то можно самому легко делать и будет максимальная гибкость, не нужно вникать в документацию этих админок.